# Making plugin for JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I am creating a JIRA plugin to fetch the issue-level permissions. Currently, the project-level permissions are working extremely fine but the issue-level permissions are not working. I tried finding a REST API to handle these permissions but, didn’t find anything so I decided to make a custom JIRA plugin to fetch the issue-level permissions of a project and handle them via exposing the plugin through an API.

My question is that what JIRA JAVA APIs do I have to use in order to handle these permissions? Or, is there any other workaround to handle issue-level permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to the "**Issue level security**" term (??)

If so, you can get the issue security level name from the "*security level*" field attached to the issues (Use a Jira account that has an active "Set Issue Security" permission, in order to work with this system issue field). This can be done by REST API that queries issue fields.

Also, the JAVA API Interface is called: '**IssueSecuritySchemes**' (at package: com.atlassian.jira.functest.framework.admin, for Jira Server/Data Center).